# Shared libraries installing gnuplot5.2

Tags: shared-libraries, gnuplot, wxwidgets, ubuntu-16.04

I am trying installing `gnuplot 5.2` on a `Xubuntu 16.04 LTS` amd64 machine.

Yesterday I successfully completed the task on another machine.

Today I followed the same protocol: installing some libraries for `cairo, pango` and `libgd`.

I then typed:

```
 ./configure --with-cairo --with-gd
 make
 make check
 sudo make install
```

The installation failed. First make check did not provide the set of checking images and `gnuplot` command exit with the following error:

```
 gnuplot: error while loading shared libraries: libwx_gtk2u_core-2.8.so.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

It tried installing `libwx_gtk2u` but the repositories install 3.0 version and the error still persists.

However `ldd /usr/bin/gnuplot` output the following line

```
 libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0 => /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libwx_gtk2u_core-3.0.so.0
```

`ldd` do not output any line containing `libwc_gtk2u_core-2.8`

I am assuming some package (libwx2.8?) or some link is missed. Any hint?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Install `libwxbase2.8-dev` and `libwxgtk2.8-dev`.

Comment: Thank you. It worked. A bit of pain searching for the packages and their dependences but it finally worked.

Comment: @jmmo If you find an answer useful then please consider accepting and/or upvoting it; see [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)